# Swift Initializer Variable 'self._' used before being initialized

Tags: swift, initialization

I have a struct called MyAccount shown below and it's giving me this error

**Variable self.record used before being initialized**

for the line `self.record = record`.  I'm confused what is going wrong here as I'm passing a `CKRecord` to `self.record` and I thought that should work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```swift
struct MyAccount: Hashable ,Identifiable, CloudItem {
    
    var record: CKRecord
    var id = UUID()
    var network: NetworksDataModel.Networks
    var username: String
    
    init?(record: CKRecord) {
        guard let newNetworkString = record.object(forKey: "network") as? String else { return }
        guard let newNetwork = NetworksDataModel.Networks(rawValue: newNetworkString) else { return }
        guard let newUsername = record.object(forKey: "username") as? String else { return }
        self.network = newNetwork
        self.username = newUsername
        self.record = record
    }
    
    init?(network: NetworksDataModel.Networks, username: String) {
        var record = CKRecord(recordType: "account")
        record["network"] = network.rawValue
        record["username"] = username
        self.init(record: record)
    }
}
```

I was thinking maybe I need to make the CKRecord optional but Im not sure why I would need to do that.  I was thinking the above code should work.

Comment: Change the `return` statements in your `guard` statements to `return nil`.   `return` by itself is an early return from a successful initialization, in cases where you want to by-pass some set-up after assigning properties.  `return nil` indicates failure.   I would expect you to get the error on the `return` rather than on the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To denote that a *failable* initializer is failing you have to return `nil`.

The three `guard` statements can be combined to one

```
init?(record: CKRecord) {
    guard let newNetworkString = record.object(forKey: "network") as? String,
          let newNetwork = NetworksDataModel.Networks(rawValue: newNetworkString),
          let newUsername = record.object(forKey: "username") as? String else { return nil }
    self.network = newNetwork
    self.username = newUsername
    self.record = record
}
```